# Preg replace in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

So basically I have a very long url, something like this -

http://www.site.com/wp-content/themes/theme/timthumb.php?src=/wp-content/uploads/2012/random-image-name.jpg&w=650&h=0&zc=1&q=100

and I would need it to automatically change the link to this -

http://www.site.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/random-image-name.jpg

I know it's doable with Javascript Preg Match, but I'm not familiar with preg match, so I'm not sure how to create that.

Could you help me craete the link?

There will be a post iwth more than 200 images in it, and I need to do it for each of the image, so best solution woudl be if it would do it for all images at once.

Comment: so these links are actually the `src` attribute of `<img>` tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Working demo** this should suffice: http://jsfiddle.net/jdAxX/1/

Hope this helps, `:)` all it does is that it takes the url `indexOf` from `?` and then split your src and use it as you require.

**code**

```
var value = "http://www.site.com/wp-content/themes/theme/timthumb.php?src=/wp-content/uploads/2012/random-image-name.jpg&w=650&h=0&zc=1&q=100";
var returnStr = value.substr(value.indexOf("?") + 1);
var spliMe = returnStr.split('&');
var newURL = "http://www.site.com"+spliMe[0].split("=")[1];
```

Comment: @user1446087 are these links in `<img>` tags?

Comment: @Alnitak Ah bruv, please guide me I will make it right, any suggestion will be taken seriously, cheers for comment and advise, `:)` (its about the comment you deleted) thnx

Comment: @Tats_innit I'd suggest formatting your code correctly, and losing the jsfiddle screen shot - it's illegible and adds nothing to the answer.

Comment: @Alnitak Thnx; is this good bruv? thanx for suggestion again! I really appreciate your time! `:)`

Comment: @Tats_innit get rid of the `document.ready` function too.  You've also now missed out the final step

Comment: @Alnitak thank-you done `:)` <added back the final step> you don't realize but I really appreciate this help to improve few things, Thank-you! **Please** let me know if I can do anything extra.

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing languages there. `preg_match` is PHP, nothing to do with JavaScript.

In JS you have various methods for using regular expressions, namely `test`, `match`, `search` and `exec` (and others). I suggest you start at http://www.regular-expressions.info for a general overview of regex and then follow with this article https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions.

Try on your own first, if you got any problems come back with some code and people will be able to help.